# How to change a variable from a structure from integer to string?

Tags: c, struct, switch-statement

The question assume

```
typedef struct {
   int day;
   int month;
   int year;
   } Date;
Date mfgDate = {17, 10, 2016}, expiryDate;

printf("%d-%d-%d", mfgDate.day, mfgDate.month, mfgDate.year);
```

By doing this i can display the date to the form of 17-10-2016, the question requires me to display the date in the form of DD-MMM-YYYY which is 17-OCT-2016, how can i do that? the question provides a tip which is to use switch statement but i can't seems to find out how, thanks a lot for help.

Comment: You could store the time in a `struct tm` and convert it with `strftime()`. And be aware that `DD-MM-YYYY` is not a good format, better would be `YYYY-MM-DD` (ISO8601), since it is unambiguous and it sorts correctly.

Comment: Minor: To print the day as `DD`, use `"%02d"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `strftime()` for that:

```
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
errno=0; //clear errno since we need it to detect errors in strftime()
//tm_year is years since 1900
//%d prints the day of the month, %B or %b the month name according to the locale
//and %Y prints the year, results in the format DD-MMMM-YYYY
int r = strftime
  (buffer, sizeof buffer, "%d-%b-%Y", &(struct tm){.tm_year=2016-1900, .tm_mon=9, .tm_mday=17} );
if(!r && errno)
{
  //do some error handling here
}
printf("%s\n",buffer);
```

Comment: Using OP's `17, 10, 2016` would add clarity.  Perhaps `.tm_year=2016-1900, .tm_mon=10-1, .tm_mday=17`?

Comment: `%b` is a closer match for OP as it uses the abbreviate name, (although likely mixed case, unlike OP implied uppercase need). `%B` is for the full name,  Still this is a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

Simply have months names in the table.

```
char *months[] = {"JAN", "FEB","MAR", ......};

printf("%d-%s-%d", mfgDate.day, months[mfgDate.month - 1], mfgDate.year);
```

Comment: I think it should be `const char *months[]` or `char months[][4]`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 it can be but it does not have to be.

Comment: @0____________ It didn't work with your previous solution `char *months = {"JAN", "FEB"....`. So much for "It does not have to be." With a `const` it would be even better since changing any of them inside the program causes UB.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just starting with C and have not learned about arrays, a switch statement is a viable choice, just for the execise

```
const char* monthname(int month)
{
    switch (month) {
        case 1: return "JAN";
        case 2: return "FEB";
        // you can fill the remaining month yourself here
        case 12: return "DEC";
        // handle the error case
        default: return "???";
    }
}
```

to print your date then use:

```
printf("%d-%s-%d", mfgDate.day, monthname(mfgDate.month), mfgDate.year);
```

Comment: Did you forget the `switch()` statement? :)

Comment: @ryyker, yes I did. Corrected.

Comment: "have not learned about arrays" --> Note that `"JAN"`, `"%d-%s-%d"`, ... are arrays.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, Yes, they are technically arrays. However they are here not used as arrays. As long as you only use constant strings, as is often the case when just starting out with C, you can get by whithout that knowledge.

Comment: OP "can get by whithout that knowledge.", yet this otherwise good answer can likewise get by without the "... and have not learned about arrays,".